# cmake native binary during cross-compile

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build a native binary for using during a cross-compile, but `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING` always seems to be set so the `${EXPORT_FILE}` never gets the native binary and the `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND` complains that native-uberplac is not found.

Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

```
set(EXPORT_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ImportExecutables.cmake) file(WRITE ${EXPORT_FILE})

if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)   MESSAGE(INFO "***CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING SET***")   SET(IMPORT_EXECUTABLES ${EXPORT_FILE})   include(${IMPORT_EXECUTABLES}) endif(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)

add_executable(uberplac src/host/uberplac.c) SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(uberplac PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${TARGET_ARCH}") CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(m sin "" uberplac_USE_LIBM) if(uberplac_USE_LIBM)   TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(uberplac m) endif()

IF(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)   SET(uberplac_EXE native-uberplac) ELSE(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)   SET(uberplac_EXE uberplac) ENDIF(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)

IF(NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)   MESSAGE(INFO "***CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING NOT SET***")   EXPORT(TARGETS uberplac FILE ${EXPORT_FILE} NAMESPACE native- ) ENDIF(NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/van_arch.h   COMMAND ${uberplac_EXE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/torpid/torpid.py ${ASM_FLAGS} -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/van_arch.h ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/vm_${ASM_ARCH}.asc   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/torpid/torpid.py uberplac )
```

Comment: My suspicion is that the build is supposed to run a native pass first to generate native binaries.. meh.. there are other ways to skin this cat.